# "Should" or just past tense?

Tags: grammaticality

I know with time clauses we only use either Present or Past tense like

If it rains, I will bring an umbrella

but NOT

If it shall/will rain,I will bring an umbrella.

But in this below example I don't understand why "should" is used instead of Past tense.[link](https://glossary.sil.org/term/future-perfect-past-tense)

"John left for the front; by the time he should return, the field would have been burnt to stubble."

Comment: It's an odd sentence. I'm not sure whether _should return_ means _was expected to return_, or whether it's saying that, from the perspective of the present day, we know that by the time he returned the field had been burnt. If the latter, I would have used _would_ rather than _should_.

Comment: But would you use "would" or "should" though? It should be Simple past because of the time clause,right? I mean it makes sense with "would" or "should"  but purely grammatically speaking past tense is the most appropriate, right?

Comment: The speaker is saying that, at the time of John's departure, his return was still in the future. That is the reason for the change of tense.

Comment: So, can I use Past tense and still be understood or is it necessary for me to use "would"?

Comment: When one says, "He said that he loved her", it doesn't mean at this time, if he (still) loves her, or doesn't love her.  Unless one refers to universal truths like, "Galileo said that the earth is round (not was round)" because the earth is still round, the above change in tense is the accepted way.

Comment: The modals have many usages; OED, if I remember correctly, takes pages to list all the ones they've found. I think this is an archaic one with the sense '[by the time] he returned'  ('a few months etc later' would be suitable and useful padding). English is rather limited when it comes to complex timeframes, the 'then future but now still past' here. Greater efforts to come up with fancy constructions were once made.

Comment: Here is a parallel example from [Goody Two Shoes](https://americanliterature.com/author/anonymous/short-story/goody-two-shoes): 'But Tommy, in order to comfort her, promised he would not fail to come back to see her, when he should return from foreign countries. ' _Here_, there is the hint of uncertainty, removed from the perspective of a later time setting in OP's example. The Goody Two Shoe example involves 'the [possible!] future in the past'.

Comment: Now I'm starting to think "should" here has an aspect of willingness and not just stating a normal futurity of his returning but a serious one or "should" is stating the probability that he is gonna arrive in some time.